# What types are automatically cast as string?

Tags: php, string, casting

I am using a third party logging library and there is a line where it runs `substr()` in a loop.  There is an `if (!is_array($value))` around it, but it seems like `$value` can wind up being pretty much any type of variable. A few weeks ago we had to put in a pull request to add `!is_object($value)` to the if statement because a different library was causing `$value` to be an object. And now we just ran into a situation where `$value` is a Resource.

So I thought this exclusionary tactic may not be maintainable, why not just do:

```
if (is_string($value){ substr($value,0,3);...
```

That doesn't work, though, because sometimes `$value` is an `int` which *can* be used in `substr()` with no complaints.

so is `if (is_string($value) || is_int($value) )` sufficient? How can I properly check if a variable is "stringable".

Because this code is running inside the app, but logging things outside of the app, we really don't want it throwing exceptions that would not bring the app down otherwise, or hide the reason the app is failing

Comment: An object and an array *can* also be cast to a string, with results which may or may not be helpful. The bigger problem I see is that you have no control over what type you're working with. What's up with that?! A program in which variables can become arbitrary types is insane.

Comment: it seems like there is more problems with your code base than just casting strings...

Comment: The key question is: what's the meaning/purpose of your three character substring? It that wasn't a relevant point, you could as well return a random string.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario that was pseudo code..

Comment: @deceze Agreed! This is Sentry-php interacting with some weird parts of exceptions that Guzzle is throwing. Apparently whatever Sentry is looping through is pretty much anything https://github.com/getsentry/raven-php/commit/e7487bfa6fb0115ae8ca8eaed64c1c64faaa126a

Comment: @celeriko my only defence is that it is not my code :p  It is code written to deal with other ppl's code though so I can understand it accepting anything and parsing through it

Comment: Not real code? Is it because you've already decided to use a shoe to drive your nail and you're only interested in shoe advice? ;-P

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I'm trying to make a quick fix to someone else's open source project bc I don't have time to internalize the library. But in a more general way I'm interested in how to accurately make sure the data is correct before running substr() on a variable and having a logging process that's supposed to be running on the side explode and take out the main app

Comment: If it isn't possible to get any context for "correct", then the `is_string()` solution you claim not to work is the only sensible one. Substrings of random stuff like `resource(4) of type (stream)` or `-1.23E+20` don't have any obvious use.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yeah using is_string() seemed the only sensible thing to me, too.. then it failed their integration tests because it was expected to work on an int().

Answer (score 1):

Objects can only be cast if they have the magic `__toString()` method. Everything else can be cast to a string, but may or may not be useful.

- Arrays are converted to the string `"Array"`
- Resources are converted to a string `"Resource id #..."`
- `null` and `false` are converted to the empty string (`""`)
- `true` is converted to the string `"1"`

More information on this is [**here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) at official documentation.

One option for dealing with values that either won't cast or don't cast to anything useful is to use `var_export($value, true)`, `serialize($value)` or one of the other serialize functions built in to PHP.

Refer [**var_export**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) and [**serialize**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) on official documentation for complete information.

Comment: +1 Serialisation would normally be a sensible option but, given that the ultimate goal is to extract a substring (for an undisclosed purpose) I wouldn't even care.